# How to run imacros with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using and learning Imacros, 
I need to extract an elementid then if extracted ID's text exact matches with any Imacro which saved in its folder it should run this imacros

I need to extract advertisers name and if any Imacros's  name matches with advertisers name Imacros should run this Imacro.

I cannot post images right now sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't even need to apply any scripting interfaces if you use 'iMacros for Firefox':

```
SET macroToRun {{!EXTRACT}}
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m={{macroToRun}}.iim
```